# Inf value after incrementation

Tags: matlab, increment, infinity

Here's my code:

```
x=0; 
for i=1:100
    x=x+sqrt(((1/((((2*i)-2)^2)*(((2*i)+2)^2)))*16)+8);
end
```

For some reason I keep getting the infinity value (inf) for x after this operation???

Can someone help explain why?

Comment: Don't use `i` as your loop variable here, because it's not clear whether you mean the variable `i` or the complex number `sqrt(-1)`. If you mean the complex number, then you should use `1i` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you divide by zero at `i==1` : Take a look at `(2*i)-2` where `i==1`.

I can only guess that you actually meant to use `i` as the imaginary square root of `-1`. In that case, change the loop to:

```
x=0;
for k=1:100 x=x+sqrt(((1/((((2*i)-2)^2)*(((2*i)+2)^2)))*16)+8); end
```

And in **that** case the loop is not necessary at all.

Answer (score 0):

When `i` equals 1 on your first iteration, the argument to SQRT equals `Inf` (i.e. you get a `1/0`, but your [divide-by-zero warning](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/10/18/controlling-warning-messages-and-state/) is probably turned off).